# Export Excel multiple image with PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

i want export excel from php with PHPExcel. My excel contain multiple image but only one image can view. How can i view the others image?  this my code

```
    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
    $objDrawing->setName("name");
    $objDrawing->setDescription("Description");

    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

    $logo = "application/views/templates/default/img/Mutiara.jpg";
    $objDrawing->setPath($logo);
    $objDrawing->setHeight(96);     
            $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
            $objDrawing->setCoordinates('H1');
```

Answer (score 1):

An individual drawing object can only have one coordinate; so taking one drawing object and setting the coordinate to A1, then setting it again to H1 is still only a single drawing object.

Once you've created the drawing object and set its main properties, clone it so that you have multiple copies, each of which can be set to different coordinates

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName("name");
$objDrawing->setDescription("Description");

$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

$logo = "application/views/templates/default/img/Mutiara.jpg";
$objDrawing->setPath($logo);
$objDrawing->setHeight(96);     
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');

$objDrawing2 = clone $objDrawing;
$objDrawing2->setCoordinates('H1');
```

Comment: i have tried to clone object but its not work. The image only view at A1 and H1 not view

Comment: In that case, you'll need to create each drawing object as a new object

Answer (score 0):

```
$assign = $line; 
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objDrawing->setPath('application/views/templates/default/img/Mutiara.jpg');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A'.$assign.'');
$objDrawing2 = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing2->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objDrawing2->setPath('application/views/templates/default/img/Mutiara.jpg');
$objDrawing2->setCoordinates('H'.$assign.'');
```

Comment: For each input restart the object "new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing()" with other variable